# Issues using the .each() method in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, methods

I have two "p" tags with the same class name like this:

```
<p class=".copyThis">Example 1</p>
<p class=".copyThis">Example 2</p>
```

I need to the contents of thes

tags to be copied to two new

tags like this:

```
<p class=".pastContentHere">Example 1</p>
<p class=".pastContentHere">Example 2</p>
```

I need to get this right using jQuery. Here’s what I have but this is not working. I'd appreciate it if someone can have a look at this…

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    var counted = false;
        $('.commentCounter span').each(function(){
                var $thisCount = $(this);
                var comCount = $thisCount.text();
                if(counted==false){
                    $('.sf_commentContainer').text(comCount);
                    counted = true;
                    alert(comCount);
                }else
                {return;}
        });

    });
</script>
```

Still very much a noob at this, so go easy on me!

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your actual issue at all, but bear in mind that the `.` should not be used in the actual class names in your markup. E.g. HTML: `<p class="whatever">...`, jQuery: `$('.whatever')...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code is not relevant. What you need can be achieved with this simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".copyThis").each(function(index) {
        $(".pastContentHere").get(index).innerHTML = $(this).html();
    });
});
```

By the way, remove the "." from the beginning of the class in the HTML.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Could you also do `$('.pastContentHere').html($(this).html());`?

Comment: @Mar no, I need one specific item from the `$('.pastContentHere')` collection in each iteration.

Comment: @Shadow: I'm curious as to why you labeled the parameter for the `.ready()` callback as `event`. More typical would be `$` since the argument passed is a reference to the global `jQuery`.

Comment: @pat sorry, still too used to the `window.onload`.. :/